# Caching binary file of the dependent packages in HomeBrew

Tags: macos, dependencies, homebrew

Say I'm installing a package A that depends on package B and C. Run `brew install A`, download and build of B succeeds, but build of C fails. I fix the error, and execute `brew install A` again. Here, what happens is HomeBrew builds package B again.

I saw it caches source code and reuses it to avoids re-download, but they don't try to reuse already built binary file. Are there any options to make HomeBrew do this? Otherwise, anyone come up with any reasons it doesn't support this feature? It's really annoying especially when the re-done build takes long.

Comment: If this happens, it's a bug; please file an issue with logs at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues.

Comment: amm could you tell me the specific URL of the issue?

Comment: There isn't one. Please open a new one!

Comment: ahhhh understand! Sorry thanks ;)